# Convert Text1.Text To Double

Tags: c#, string, double

I am doing everything that answers show, yet I get an error related to a datetime string:

> When converting a string to DateTime [not trying to], parse the string to take the date before putting eacdh variable into the DateTime object

Not trying to convert to a date at all - this is a string to double only.

All of these fail with the exact error message above this, *yet these are listed as answers to the problem on this site*:

```
Convert.ToDouble(text1.Text);
Convert.ToDouble(Convert.ToString(text1.Text));
Double.TryParse(text1.Text, out value);
Double.Parse(text1.Text).ToString();
Double.Parse(text1.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

What am I entering in the box to have it throw this error?

```
[nothing]
a
x
b
c
```

I am trying to convert a string to a double; when I look at the properties of Text1.Text, [it is listed as a string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.text(v=vs.110).aspx), so I would think that trying to convert a string to a string before converting to a decimal (woah) is redundant.  As you can see, I still tried that *just in case*.

[In one of MS's examples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t7xswkc6(v=vs.110).aspx), they use this with decimals:

```
CultureInfo culture;
decimal number = Decimal.Parse(text1.Text, culture.NumberFormat);
```

I get a use of unassigned local variable error on this (`culture`); also, I don't see this listed anywhere in another other example, so this is a very peculiar approach to solving it, but maybe this is the new way to do this?

A different test, with one being direct input in the code, the other coming from the textbox:

```
/// No error:
Convert.ToDouble("0.85");
/// Error:
Convert.ToDouble(txt1.Text);
```

Stack Trace of `Convert.ToDouble(txt1.Text);`:

> at System.Number.ParseDouble(String value, NumberStyles options,
>   NumberFormatInfo numfmt)    at System.Convert.ToDouble(String value)
>   at BaseUtilityForm.Form1.btnDone_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
>   c:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\Project\Project\Project.cs:line 89    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons
>   button, Int32 clicks)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)

The format exception message:

```
{"Input string was not in a correct format."}
```

Comment: Can you provide a short and complete example program that duplicates your exception?  Regarding your `CultureInfo` question, you have forgotten to instantiate the class as the example does:  `culture = new CultureInfo(locale);`  Also calling `Convert.ToString` _on a string_ makes no sense.

Comment: Agree with @IvanStoev.  The code shown doesn't seem like the culprit.  Can you add the stack trace of the exception?

Comment: @Quantic Nope, none of these textboxes are `DateTime` fields and nothing is being convert to a DateTime with this.  I'm not using anything date related.  What's odd is that it will validate a double - like if I enter 1 or 2.  As soon as it's anything from A to Z, or a blank, I get this `DateTime` error.

Comment: That stack shows a different exception than  the one in the original question. Parse EXPECTS that the text being parsed CAN be converted - in your case it cannot so the exception occurs. if you stick with the TryParse it will only give a value when the text can be converted.

Comment: Ok despite my now deleted comments you are correct, `Convert.ToDouble("a");` gives a *troubleshooting tip* of "When converting a string to DateTime, parse the string to take the date before putting each variable into the DateTime object". I don't know where those tips come from but its message is wrong. The tip links to the actual exception, a format exception [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.formatexception(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @Quantic Thanks, lol - yeah, that's what threw me at first when I saw the `DateTime`; it looks like some generic error.

Comment: @Theo - you are correct; that worked - I had to create a double variable, parse on the next line, then validate.  Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, my apologies. Weird message coming from `FormatException` for any type - `double`, `decimal` etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the message received is confusing, but the root cause is that these conversion methods expect that the text value CAN be converted. If the text value cannot be converted an exception occurs.

```
Convert.ToDouble(text1.Text);
Convert.ToDouble(Convert.ToString(text1.Text));
Double.Parse(text1.Text).ToString();
Double.Parse(text1.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

To avoid an exception:

```
double value;
if(Double.TryParse(text1.Text, out value)
{
   [...do stuff with valid value here...]
}
```

Comment: Thanks again; and yes, the error makes the question about even more confusing, since a date has nothing to do with it, but I can understand how that misleads.

Comment: ;) yep only too true. Thanks to Quantic for pointing that one out!